# When to compress files with Node.js

Tags: node.js, compression, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to better understand the static file serving process in Node.js.  I think I have a pretty good handle on everything with the exception of file compression. Many references seem to imply that you should compress files on the fly. Express seems to use this approach in its [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) middleware.

Given the [memory / time](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_memory_usage_tuning) concerns associated with compressing files and the static nature of the files to be compressed, why would you compress these on the fly rather than compressing them as part of a build step or something like that?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing quite a bit of research and experimenting myself, my conclusion is there really is no reason NOT to compress your static files ahead of time if you are serving your files straight from Node.

I ended up compressing my large static files as part of a build step by piping it through unix's `gzip` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few reasons:

- New files are added to the library.  You may not want to re-build everything everytime there is a new file added or changed.
- The encoding algorithm used is actually used for compression and encryption which requires a dynamically generated key to decode.
- Adaptive Huffman encoding doesn't use a lot of memory and processing power.
- You can pack multiple small files together and send it at once instead of making HTTP request back and forth.
- You can customize the encoding algorithm to support sending in chunks for large files, which makes stop and resume possible.
- Depending on the application, sometimes it make sense to keep files in memory if it gets sent all the time instead of reading it off the storage medium every single time.

Comment: I could see some these reasons applying for dynamic content, but I'm not sure about static content.  If you're swapping out a static file (e.g. CSS, JS) then you're probably re-building things and you can "pack multiple files together" whether you gzip on the fly or beforehand.